# Can i XOR an array of bytes with an equal length key securely

Tags: symmetric, xor

If i have say 64 bytes, can i XOR those bytes with another 64 random bytes, and have two new arrays, where both are needed to reconstruct the first?

Intuetively i need some symmetric encryption like AES, but i cant figure out how the XOR above can be attacked. Does the content matter?

Comment: Have you ever consider generating a random 65 byte then xor like in OTP?

Comment: It's secure if you do it a single time with each key. If you reuse the same key, it is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i have say 64 bytes, can i XOR those bytes with another 64 random bytes, and have two new arrays, where both are needed to reconstruct the first?

This is known as [XOR secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#t_=_n) or in the case of two splits also known as a the (binary) [One-Time-Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

Indeed if for every execution of the split-up operation a new independent random string is used then always both (/all) shared parts are needed for reconstruction. Any less number of shares / parts leaks no information about the shared message except for the length and what was already known anyways.

Note though that this provides *no* protection against tampering, i.e. if somebody flips a bit in either share and the other(s) doesn't then the reconstructed message will have the bit flip without a strong cryptographic guarantee of this being noticed.

Also note that security breaks down horribly if the same randomness is used with two different messages. Of course if you re-use randomness for the same message then an adversary can notice that.

Comment: Thank you, fascinating, I can explain that to a 10 year old, but not AES :)